# Looking for "super icons" to organize Windows 7 Quick Launch toolbar

Tags: windows-7, icons, toolbar, quicklaunch

I am looking for special icons (I'll call them "super icons" here) for the Windows 7 Quick Launch toolbar.

These super icons, as I envision them, have the property that, upon clicking one of them, several other icons "pop out", which can be clicked like any other Quick Launch icon, to launch a program.  (The idea, of course, is that these "super icons" can be used to group icons, and thus reduce the number of icons at the "top level" of the Quick Launch toolbar.)

> How can I do this (preferably without having to purchase some app)?

(I see no reason to limit this kind of organization to one level, IOW, it would be fine with me if "super icons" could contain other "super icons", but this would be only frosting on the cake, AFAIC.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is probably most widely known (at least to OSX users) as [Stacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacks_(Mac_OS)), as that is what Apple calls it on the OSX Dock.

There are a number of tools for windows which replicate this functionality, but the one I found first was [7stacks](http://alastria.com/software/7stacks/).

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using Folders. Navigate to the Quick Launch directory:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch
```

Right-click, choose New > Folder, and type a name for your "super icon". Now place your shortcuts in this sub folder.